# Logging nested functions using joblib Parallel and delayed calls

Tags: python, logging, python-logging

In one of my scripts I have something like:

```py
import logging
from joblib import Parallel, delayed

def f_A(x):
    logging.info("f_A "+str(x))

def f_B():
    logging.info("f_B")
    res = Parallel(n_jobs=2, prefer="processes")(delayed(f_A)(x) for x in range(10))


if __name__ == "__main__":
   logging.basicConfig(level=logging.INFO)
   f_B()
```

I would expect that when I run `python script.py` something like:

```
INFO:root:f_B
INFO:root:f_A
```

to be shown in the console, instead I see:

```
INFO:root:f_B
```

but no information from `f_A` is shown.

How can I get `f_A` --and eventually functions called from there-- to show in the logs?

I think the issue is due to default logging level that is DEBUG and the main process doesn't share propagate the level to the children. If you modify slightly the script to:

```py
import logging
from joblib import Parallel, delayed

def f_A(x):
    logging.basicConfig(level=logging.INFO)
    logging.info("f_A "+str(x))

def f_B():
    logging.info("f_B")
    res = Parallel(n_jobs=2, prefer="processes")(delayed(f_A)(x) for x in range(10))


if __name__ == "__main__":
   logging.basicConfig(level=logging.INFO)
   f_B()
```

then everything works as intended.

Comment: Very relevant question. It is indeed telling that joblib only uses print in their examples and not logging. Their issue tracker has this issue, which contains two work-arounds: https://github.com/joblib/joblib/issues/1017 .

Answer (score 1):

You are correct the issue is due to the logging level not being propagated to the child processes. In your original script, the `basicConfig` is only called in the main process. When using the `joblib.Parallel` with the `prefer="processes"` option, the child processes do not inherit the logging configuration of the main process.